# Changing font color of Bootstrap Navbar 3.4.1

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Hi I want to change the font color of the bootstrap navbar links and already tried setting a specific class to the navbar like those suggested in other posts similar to this. However, I only managed to change the font of the navbar brand. Can you give any suggestions? Is there a problem with my specificity?

```css
  header{
        margin-top: 1em;
        }
    .navbar-main{
        background-color: #00cc99;
    }
    .navbar .navbar-www{
        color: white;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

      <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-main">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand navbar-www">Kau Unlimited</a>
                    </div> 
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-www">
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"></ul>
                </div>  
            </nav>
```

I'm still an absolute beginner at coding and trying to avoid !important and still learning on specificity.
Thank you!

Comment: use !important in your css it will work i.e:   .navbar .navbar-www{
        color: white !important;
    }

Answer (score 0):

```css
header{
    margin-top: 1em;
    }
.navbar-main{
    background-color: #00cc99;
}
.navbar-www li a{
    color: white !important;
```

```html
<header> 
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-main">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand navbar-www">Kau Unlimited</a>
                </div> 
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-www">
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"></ul>
            </div>  
        </nav>
    </header>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to avoid using !important right now.

Comment: without using !important you cannot override bootstrap classes.

Comment: @FerinPatel this is not right. You can easily override the external library CSS by adding some extra selectors.

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid !important as it is a bad habit. You can override the bootstrap CSS by adding some extra classes to your navbar or may be any ID.

Here is what you can do to change the navlink text color

```
.navbar-www.navbar-brand li a{
color:#fff;
}
```

If this doesn't override, try to add some id in you navbar and make your css code something like this.

```
#navbar.navbar-www.navbar-brand li a{
color:#fff;
}
```

You can easily check in the console, what is the styling of the nav link bootstrap. You can override this by adding one extra selector, either it is class, attribute, id, or any parent selector.

Comment: Hi! thanks a lot! I forgot about using the console and  found the styling and used it to override the thee bootstrap in this way and it worked. 


header{
 margin-top: 1em;
 }
.navbar-main{
 background-color: #00cc99;
}
.navbar .navbar-www,.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
 color: white;
}

Answer (score 0):

You need to add color for link please replace  **.navbar .navbar-www**  this with  **.navbar .navbar-www a** please check below

```css
 header{
        margin-top: 1em;
        }
    .navbar-main{
        background-color: #00cc99;
    }
    .navbar .navbar-www a{
        color: white;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

      <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-main">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand navbar-www">Kau Unlimited</a>
                    </div> 
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-www">
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"></ul>
                </div>  
            </nav>
```